# Popup in WPF does not open

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid with modified column header which contain a button which shall open a popup.
This is written in code behind because of different data sources with different number of columns.

That's how it looks like:

[image]

Popups are stored in:

```
Dictionary<string, Popup> HeaderPopups = new Dictionary<string, Popup>();
```

And here the code behind:

```
dgMaterials.AutoGeneratingColumn += (ss, ee) =>
{
    Button b = new Button() { Content = "...", Name = "btn_" + ee.PropertyName, Margin = new Thickness(3) };
    b.Click += HeaderFilterButtonClick;
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = ee.PropertyName, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center });
    stackPanel.Children.Add(b);
    ee.Column.Header = stackPanel;

    Popup pop = new Popup() { Name = "pop_" + ee.PropertyName, Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom, PlacementTarget = b, StaysOpen = false, Width = 200, Margin = new Thickness(3) };
    Border bord = new Border() { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1,1,1,1) };
    pop.DataContext = bord;

    HeaderPopups.Add(ee.PropertyName, pop);

    StackPanel stack = new StackPanel() { Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 15) };
    bord.DataContext = stack;

    StackPanel stackButtons = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 15) };

    Button bAll = new Button() { Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), Name = "btnAll_" + ee.PropertyName };
    bAll.Click += btnAllClick;
    TextBlock txtAll = new TextBlock() { Text = "Select All", Foreground = Brushes.Blue, Cursor = Cursors.Hand };
    bAll.Content = txtAll;

    Button bNone = new Button() { Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0), Name = "btnNone_" + ee.PropertyName };
    bNone.Click += btnNoneClick;
    TextBlock txtNone = new TextBlock() { Text = "Select None", Foreground = Brushes.Blue, Cursor = Cursors.Hand };
    bNone.Content = txtNone;

    stackButtons.Children.Add(bAll);
    stackButtons.Children.Add(bNone);

    ListBox list = new ListBox() { Name = "lst_" + ee.PropertyName, BorderThickness = new Thickness(0) };

    stack.Children.Add(stackButtons);
    stack.Children.Add(list);
};
```

So for each column a popup is generated and I have the popups with the keys Spec_No, Grade and Class in my HeaderPopups dictionary.

I want the appropriate popups to show up beneath the clicked button, like in the example from http://www.jarloo.com/excel-like-autofilter-in-wpf/

Look here:

[image]

My problem is to open these popups in HeaderFilterButtonClick-Event. I tried it with:

```
private void HeaderFilterButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    txtTest.Text += e.OriginalSource.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    txtTest.Text += e.Source.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    txtTest.Text += b.Name;

    if (b.Name == "btn_Spec_No")
    {
        HeaderPopups["Spec_No"].IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Where do you store the `Popup` that you create in the event handler...? Where do you expect to find it?

Comment: thanks for reply and sry for stupid question. just edited the title and body. now I use a dictionary for my popups, but the new problem is, that they do not open :/

Comment: Where do you want it to show up?

Comment: beneath the clicked button, see edited post

Comment: You are misusing `DataContext`. 
When you want to assign Childcontrols you usually use `Content` or `Children`

Comment: It's not something stupid like they open and then immediately close again due to the button click stealing focus? What happens if you set `StaysOpen="True"`

Comment: that's what I just learned, thank you all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Popup` is currently empty and thus completely invisible.

You should set the `Child` property of it to the `Border` and also set the `Child` property of the `Border` to something for it to render:

```
Popup pop = new Popup() { ... };
Border bord = new Border() { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1) };
bord.Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "some content..." };
pop.Child = bord;
```

Answer (score 1):

The popup is opening and rendering, but it is empty, so it can't be seen.

the problem is here

```
 Border bord = new Border() { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1,1,1,1) };
 pop.DataContext = bord;
```

`Datacontext` is used to set Binding targets, which an empty popup has no bindings.

You need the fill the child object instead by changing the above into

```
 Border bord = new Border() { Background = Brushes.White, BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1,1,1,1) };
pop.Child = bord;
```

this sets the root of the popup container to ther Border object.
You will also have to do the same with the stack panel and border

```
StackPanel stack = new StackPanel() { Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 15) };
bord.Child = stack;
```